# How to merge multiple tables with similar names in MySQL from different Databases

Tags: java, sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

Please help me in finding a solution for

merging multiple tables with similar names in MySQL [duplicate] from different Databases

Comment: What you mean by `merging multiple tables`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Please consider giving an example. Do you want to populate new tables with the `UNION` of the rows in some existing tables?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered without more details.

Comment: Our application was deployed in Multiple Schema based on the Locations.

Now we are going to merge the data of different databases to single database of MySql

As I am new to Database Migration , I really likes to take advice of experts.

1) Any good tools can be used for this process.

2) What are the precautions to be done for this.

The application is in Spring,Hibernate, Java

Database is MySql

Answer (score 1):

Our application was deployed in Multiple Schema based on the Locations.

Now we are going to merge the data of different databases to single database of MySql

As I am new to Database Migration , I really likes to take advice of experts.

1) Any good tools can be used for this process.

2) What are the precautions to be done for this.

The application is in Spring,Hibernate, Java

Database is MySql

Answer (score 0):

you should use table name with there database name..

For example if you want to merge as union or join the use table name as:

Select * from db_name1.table_name
union 
select * from db_name2.table_name...

Otherwise clarify your question.